# Hiding and showing panels

Tags: c#, .net, installation, panel

**EDIT**
I've found and posted the solution.

I am trying to make an installer for my application and I am trying to do that with panels (I don't know if this is a good way of doing it, but this gives me more customization options instead of using the install shield program). What would be the best way to do this?
This is the code I have right know:

**C# Code**

```
foreach (var c in Controls)
{
    if (!(c is Panel)) continue;
    if (c.Name == "pnlBottom") continue;
        
    c.Visible = c.Name.Contains(_currentPanel.ToString());
    
    if (c.Visible) return;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your specific question is but if you are just trying to show/hide panels then you could do it directly. _firstPanel.Visible = true; _secondPanel.Visible = false; Then once the user moves from the first panel to the second, through a button click or whatever, you would just _firstPanel.Visible = false; _secondPanel.Visible = true;

Comment: But what if I have like 10 panels? Is there a method to make it easier? (To make my code shorter?)

Comment: You could turn your above code into a method and pass in the name of the panel (panelNameToShow) you want to show and then hide all other panels. The logic would be very similar to what you have, you would need to change c.Name.Contains(_currentPanel.ToString()) to c.Name.Equals(panelNameToShow)

Comment: Okai, sounds like that could be the solution yea, thx, I'll try this :)!

Comment: Good luck :) If you cant get it to work I can post the method. I'm just not at a computer with Visual Studio right now.

Comment: Alright it works, I'll post the solution :D!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this, it changes the Visibility of a single Panel:

```
private void PanelVisible(string panelName, bool visible)
{
    var panel = this.Controls.OfType<Panel>().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == panelName);
    if (panel != default(Panel)) panel.Visible = visible;
}
```

If you want to make all Invisible, but one:

```
private void PanelVisible(string panelName)
{
    foreach(var panel in this.Controls.OfType<Panel>().Where(p=>p.Name!="pnlBottom"))
    {
        panel.Visible = panel.Name == panelName;
    }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to add your exception regarding the panel with the name "pnlBottom".

See edit

Comment: for functionality and intelligent where :D +1

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I use to show a panel:

```
foreach (var c in Controls)
{
    if (!(c is Panel)) continue;
    if (c.Name == "pnlBottom") continue;
        
    c.Visible = c.Name.Contains(_currentPanel.ToString());
    
    if (c.Visible) return;
}
```

And this is the code I use to call it and browse through my panels:
**Next button**

```
private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (pnlContent1.Visible) { ShowPanel("2"); return; }
    if (pnlContent2.Visible) { ShowPanel("3"); return; }
    if (pnlContent3.Visible) { ShowPanel("4"); return; }
    if (pnlContent4.Visible) { ShowPanel("5"); return; }
}
```

**Back button**

```
private void btnBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (pnlContent2.Visible) { ShowPanel("1"); return; }
    if (pnlContent3.Visible) { ShowPanel("2"); return; }
    if (pnlContent4.Visible) { ShowPanel("3"); return; }
    if (pnlContent5.Visible) { ShowPanel("4"); return; }
}
```

I hope this will be use to someone else as well :D!

Comment: What your code does, is make all Panels Invisible, till it finds the one to make visible. That is due to your return statement, since it makes the code jump out of the whole procedure.